Domain of injectivity of a complex cubic polynomial
Question: How to find the domain of injectivity of a complex polynomial having at least two distinct critical points?
In particular, for $P(z)=a+bz+cz^2+dz^3$ where $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers, what is the domain of injectivity of $P$? In other words, does there exist $\epsilon>0$ such that any sector formed by two rays emanating from that critical point with opening less than $\epsilon$, $P$ is injective in those sectors?
My argument: As we know a polynomial is not injective in some neighbourhood of a critical point (where $P'(z)=0$). When we have a polynomial with only one critical point (unicritical polynomial), we shall always have some sector formed by two rays emanating from that critical point in which the polynomial is injective ( I have checked). But if $P(z)=a+bz+cz^2+dz^3$ has two distinct critical points how to handle the situation?
Can anyone suggest some ideas? Thank you.

Hint n°1 :
Injectivity means
$$\text{for any} \ z_1,z_2, \ \ P(z_1)=P(z_2) \implies z_1=z_2$$
But
$$P(z_1)-P(z_2)=0 \iff b(z_1-z_2)+c(z_1^2-z_2^2)+d(z_1^3-z_2^3)=0$$
$$\iff (z_1-z_2)\left[\underbrace{b+c(z_1+z_2)+d(z_1^2+z_1z_2+z_2^2)}_{Q(z_1,z_2)}\right]=0$$
As a consequence, you have to find a domain $D$ where
$$\text{for any} \ z_1,z_2 \in D, \ \ Q(z_1,z_2)\neq 0$$
Edit : I have written a program displaying

the triangle whose vertices are the roots of $P$ (in black)

the roots of $P'$ (black points inside this triangle which are the foci of a certain ellipse ; see Hint 2 below. Common abscissa 2/3).

a certain number of "$\Lambda$ shapes".


Let us explain what these shapes represent. For a given value of $z_1$, let $z_2$ and $z_2'$ be the two roots of quadratic equation  $Q(z_1,z_2)=0$. The corresponding "$\Lambda$ shape" has its top in $z_1$ and its two feet are points $z_2$ and $z_2'$.
Let $(\Pi)$ be the half-plane defined by $\Re(z)>2/3$ (i.e., the halfplane on the right of the roots of the derivative) ; for any $z_1 \in (\Pi)$, there is at most one among $z_2$ and $z_2'$ which belongs to half-plane $(\Pi)$.
And this phenomena is the same in all simulations.

Therefore (as the above is by no means a proof !) we can express the conjecture that the line joining the two roots of $P'$ divides the complex plane into two domains of injectivity $\Re(z)>a$ and symmetricaly $\Re(z)<a$ (here with $a=2/3$).
[Caution : we have presented here one of the two cases. The other case, when the roots of $P'$ are both real, a similar partition   exists, this time with planes $Im(z)>0$ and $Im(z)<0$].
Important remark regarding critical points : $Q(z,z)=P'(z)$.

Hint n°2 : a particular case of Lucas theorem :
If $z_1,z_2,z_3$ are the roots of polynomial $P$ (defining a triangle $(T)$), then the roots $z'_1,z'_2$ of $P'$, are located inside triangle $(T)$, moreover they are the foci of the maximal ellipse inscribed in triangle $(T)$.

Thanks, @Jean Marie for your answer, but I am looking for something more.  I want to know the answer in terms of $\epsilon$ and sector as I have asked in the question because it is not possible to find ${(z_1,z_2): Q(z_1,z_2)=0}$ manually for higher degree polynomial. Can you suggest some other directions?

I just added a graphical simulation from which I infer a certain conjecture.

An interesting argument in this answer
